# How to wait for an HTML page and get result when page complitely created?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, github

I have a page (page1.html) and I want to send an ajax to page2.html (http://m-kermani.github.io/getapp.html) and page2.html has an iframe that made by javascript

I made it by javaScript because I need to send a parameter to the page3

In page1.html I have:

```
$.get('https://m-kermani.github.io/getapp.html', function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

and I just need the iframe content but beacuse it made by JavaScript I can't get it and that did not created!  (This is the way JavaScirpt is)

I need to send ajax request and get the iframe content because I need an https domain for some reasons that GitHub.io is!

No I need to know **is there anyway I can get the content of the iframe from GitHub page?**

**Is there any other way I can direly just have GitHub page and give the parameter to it and can get the content of the page3 (not using server side language)?**

**And suggestion about what can I do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to circumcent the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). Unless the API you're trying to access specifically supports a way to do it ([CORS, JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy), etc), you can't do it. You should read the documentation of the API you're trying to access to see if they support accessing it from the client side.

Comment: I'm developing Google Chrome extension and it does not allow me to send ajax request to non https domains and I don't own https and I just wanted to do this tricks to solve the problem, you know github is https ;)

Comment: That's a terrible hack. Just get https for your own website.

Comment: Now I think so! At least I gave it a try and now more about Same-origin policy

Comment: Protip: [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) provides legitimate free certificates. It's a bit of work to set up though.

Comment: Thank you; I will try to set it

Answer (score 1):

An Ajax request is just a request for a resource. It just gets whatever the server is going to send. It doesn't automatically render the HTML and fetch dependant resources.

If you want the content of a frame, then you have to request the URL for the frame instead of the URL for the page with the `<iframe>` tag in it.

(The [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) will still apply).

Comment: Let me tell you what is the problem; I am developing a chrome extension and it asks me to send request to https but my own domain is not https and I was looking for a way to do it (github is https)